# How to resolve gradle warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

How to resolve the following gradle warning? I added the library by this line:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'


Warning:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.collections.ReferenceMap$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `-keepattributes InnerClasses` in your ProGuard config

edit : try with `-dontoptimize`